# i want to show attendnce of a particular date in mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

i have a schema like this:

```
               var UserSchema   = new Schema({
             name: String,
              username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
             password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
             attendence: [{
                    month   :{type:String},
                    year    :{type:String},
                    day     :{ type:String},
                    attended:{type: Boolean}

            }]          
         });
```

I want to show the attended ie attendence of this for each date(combined by month+year+day) against each user name in angular js table wiyh nodejs and mongodb. in moongose.

Comment: And where are you stuck in all those tasks? You don't know how to query mongo for that? Or are you having trouble displaying the results with angular? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Btw, Mongo has a [Date type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) specifically so you don't have to store it like that.

Comment: with date type its also showing time .i don't want time becauz that creating an ambiguity. i want to store single record of each user for a particular date

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will helps u..

*this is client side angular js code to  a userdetaile to insert in database using date and time.*

```
    <form method="post" name="ravi" action="/">
  username:   <input type="text"  placeholder="username" name="user"  required><br/>
     date :<input type="number" placeholder="year"  name="year" min="2015" max="2017" required>
      <input type="number" placeholder="month"  name="month" min="1" max="12" required>
      <input type="number" placeholder="day" name="day" min="1" max="31" required><br/>
     Time:  <input type="number" placeholder="HH"  name="hour" min="0" max="23" required>
      <input type="number" placeholder="MM" name="minutes" min="0" max="59" required><br/>
            <input type="submit" >
    </form>
```

*this is server side  to inserting userdetaile in database using date and time..*

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/bhawna", function(err, db) {
  if(err) { return console.dir(err); }
  var collection2 = db.collection('sadulehistory');


     var searchitem = (req.body.user).toUpperCase();
     console.log(searchitem);
     //var searchitem1 =(req.params.aa)
     //console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.search));
     var yr = req.body.year;
     var moy = req.body.month;
     var dom = req.body.day;
     var hr = req.body.hour;
     var mnt = req.body.minutes;


     collection2.insert({
         'searchitem': searchitem,
         'Scheduledtime': (new Date(yr, (moy - 1), dom, hr, mnt)).toLocaleString(),
         'CurrentTime': (new Date()).toLocaleString()
     }, function(err, result) {});

     res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000/")
     res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
     res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
     res.redirect('back');
});
```

Comment: ----------------------------------

                       Name    Attendence for 20-10-2015

                          ------------------------------------

                           Akash     true

                            Nitin     False

               ----------------------------------                                                            I want attendence like this that for a particular date its attendence is  shown ...i want to display it in a table

Comment: please explain what format do you want to show attendence

Comment: I have made a drop down on a page in which we select date,month and year and that goes into url of next page like http://localhost:8080/users/showAttendence/6/1/2015 where 6-date, 1-month and 2015-year and then on next page i want to show   a table with two columns one having name and other showing attendence  of the date in the url

Comment: i did this but what i want is some users don't have attendence for that date but i also want to display their name but in attendence column as blank becoz they don't have attendence. in back end i used   ---       apiRouter.route('/users/showAttendence/:day/:month/:year')
  .get(function(req, res){
   console.log(req.params.day),
   User.find({'attendence.day':req.params.day,'attendence.month':req.params.month,'attendence.year':req.params.year},{'attendence.$': 1},function(err, obj){
         console.log(obj);
   });

  });

Comment: if you want to search attendence by date then it only shows results of present users of that day...

Comment: if you want to display all users do you should use User.find({},function(err, obj){ console.log(obj); });

Comment: i want to display in angularjs page ... and as you can see the schema i want attendence for a particular date....which matches the date in url....

Comment: in response of: if you want to search attendence by date then it only shows results of present users of that day.   --i want to give a date and show attendence for that date for all users

Comment: what is {'attendence.$': 1} in your query

Comment: to project attendence.i have used it but its not wrking properly....when there is single attendence record for a date in 1 user it shows only that attendence record. but when we have record for a date in all users then it shows only their 1 record of attendence not the one asked in url(ie date)

Answer (score 0):

hello bhawna this code must help you...
attendence client side code for users attendence..index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Attendence</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="gray">

    <a href="Shistory.html">Attendence Listing</a>
    <div id="container" >
         <h1 align="center"> Attendence </h1>
<div align="center">
<form method="post" name="ravi" action="/">
 <input type="text"  placeholder="Name" name="Item"  required><br/>
 date :<input type="number" placeholder="year"  name="year" min="2015" max="2017" required>
  <input type="number" placeholder="month"  name="month" min="1" max="12" required>
  <input type="number" placeholder="day" name="day" min="1" max="31" required><br/>
 attended:<select name="attended">
  <option value="Present">Present</option>
  <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
    </select>
<br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Insert attendence" >
</form>
</div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and code for searching users using date code.. Shistory.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Attendence</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="gray">
    <a href="index.html">Attendence</a>
    <div id="container" >
<div align="center">
 <h1 align="center"> Attendence Listing </h1>
<form method="post" name="ravi1" action="/a">
 date :<input type="number" placeholder="year"  ng-model="year"  name="year" min="2015" max="2017" required>
  <input type="number" placeholder="month"  ng-model="month" name="month" min="1" max="12" required>
  <input type="number" placeholder="day"  ng-model="day" name="day" min="1" max="31" required><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="attendence">
</form>
</div>


    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and your serverside code.. server.js

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var connect = require('connect'),
 bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var ObjectId=require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var     BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
    express = require("express"),
    app = express(); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));


       // app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/angular'));
    // index.html and Sdistory.html in public folder
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
            app.get("/",function(req,res){
              res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
            });


        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/bhawna", function(err, db) {
          if(err) { return console.dir(err); }
          var collection2 = db.collection('users');
        app.post('/a',function(req,res){
        //console.log("hello");

        var qqw=req.body.year;
        var qqw2=req.body.month;
        var qqw3=req.body.day;
                    collection2.find({'Scheduledtime':(new Date(qqw, (qqw2-1), qqw3)).toLocaleString()}).toArray(function(err,resu)
        {
            res.end( JSON.stringify(resu));
        console.log(resu);
                                        }
        );
        });
        app.post('/',function(req,res){

         var searchitem =(req.body.Item).toUpperCase();

                var  yr=req.body.year;
                var moy=req.body.month;
                var dom=req.body.day;
                var attended=req.body.attended;

         collection2.insert({'userd':searchitem,'Scheduledtime':(new Date(yr, (moy-1), dom)).toLocaleString(),'Attended':attended},function(err,result){});

        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:8080/")
              re

s.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
           res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.redirect('back');



      });  
    });
    app.listen(8080,function(){
      console.log("It's Started on PORT 8080");
    });
```

Comment: i much part i have also made....i wand to fetch attendence ie  app.post('/',function(req,res) part i need to fetch the records in form of a table

Comment: yes in front -end i am using angularjs to display the table

Comment: the thing i was trying to do is not possible with attendence in userschema ........i have to make another schema for attendence

Comment: BhawnaMalhotra i have tried RavindraGalav's answer it work fine to insert attendance with name and date..there is no need of another schema

Comment: @BhawnaMalhotra if you find this helpful then please click to acceptance of this answer.

Comment: i am able to insert records but problem is while displaying

Comment: @BhawnaMalhotra then shoe your angular code i will help you??

Comment: i got the solution @ donno1

Comment: apiRouter.route('/users/showAttendence/:day/:month/:year')
  .get(function(req, res){
   var userAttendenceList = []; 

   User.find({},function(err,users){

    Attendence.find({ 'day': req.params.day ,'month': req.params.month ,'year': req.params.year},function(err,currentDateAttendence){
      
      users.forEach(function(user,index){
      
      var userAttendence = new Object();
      userAttendence.user = user;

      var defaultAttendence = new Object();
      defaultAttendence.attended = false;
      userAttendence.attendence = defaultAttendence;

Comment: currentDateAttendence.forEach(function(attendence,index){
       
       console.log(user._id);
       console.log(attendence.User._id);
       if(user._id.toString() == attendence.User.toString()){
        console.log(user._id);
        console.log(attendence.User);
        userAttendence.attendence = attendence;
        }
      });

      userAttendenceList.push(userAttendence);
     });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(userAttendenceList));
      res.json(userAttendenceList);
    }); 
   });
  });

Comment: <html>
 <div ng-init= "user.getAttendence()">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Username</th>
     <th>Attendence</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in user.attendence">
     <td>{{ person.user.name }}</td>
     <td>{{person.attendence.attended}}</td>
    <tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</html>

Comment: ---------controller code------------- //function to get attendence of a particular date ie. for page(http://localhost:8080/users/showAttendence/:day/:month/:year)
 vm.getAttendence=function(){
  vm.processing = true;
  vm.message = '';
  Attendence.getParticularDateAttendence($routeParams.day,$routeParams.month,$routeParams.year)
  .success(function(data){
   vm.attendence = data;
   vm.processing = false;
  });
 };
});
service code:
 attendenceFactory.getParticularDateAttendence = function(day,month,year){
  return $http.get('/api/users/showAttendence/'+ day + '/' + month + '/' + year);
 }